# Get Subject value from child component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to pass a subject into a child component:

**Parent:**

Component

```
public dataStream$ = new Subject<Array<string>>()

ngOnInit () {
  this.dataStreams$.next(['hello!'])
}
```

Template

`<child-component [dataStream]="dataStream$" />`

**Child:**

Component

```
Input('dataStream') dataStream$: Subject<Array<string>>

ngOnInit () {
  this.dataStreams$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

===

Clearly this will never `console.log()`, the Subject has the `.next()` called before `ngOnInit` is called on the child component.

The question is, how do I get the value of `Subject.startWith()` into a child component?

Is the best option to use a Behaviour subject?  In that case it would be initiated with an `undefined` value and I'd have to filter that out in the child.

Comment: Why don't you just pass ['hello'] to your input, and use ngOnChanges to know when the input changes? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    if ( changes['activities'] !== undefined) {
      this.activitiesStream$.next(changes['activities'].currentValue)
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a stackblitz that demonstrates Parent=>child component communication using observable. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5frgtn